# Bind dialogopen event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Jquery dialog set up with id as below.

In document.ready

```
$('#modal-id').dialog({ autoOpen: false, ...... })
```

and in html

```
<div id="modal-id">
<div class="modal-content">
.....
</div>
</div>
```

Now I need to bind the open event of the dialog.

```
$( "#modal-id" ).bind( "dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
....
});
```

The above works but the below doesn't work

```
$( ".ui-dialog-content" ).bind( "dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
...
});
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

```
$( ".ui-dialog" ).live( "dialogopen", function(event, ui) {
$.getScript("/common/js/jquery.curvycorners.min.js", function() {
});
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to bind the event to the ui-dialog-content?

Comment: So that it can be used for all the dialogs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I don't think the class you want is `.ui-dialog-content`, but `ui-dialog` (I might be mistaken though). My suggestion would be to use the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method (or [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) if using an old jQuery):

```
$(document).on("dialogopen", ".ui-dialog", function(event, ui) {
    ...
});
```

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/WdFcX/).

Comment: Nice answer, My bad that I tried ui-dialog with bind but not live! Thanks :)

Comment: I have another problem now, I inserted a getScript inside this function but its not working. Any ideas? Please check update for info.

Comment: I never used getScript, so there's not much I can do to help. I'd suggest expressing it as a simple `$.ajax` call as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), using also an `error` function besides the `success`. If the problem is in the ajax call, it will show.

Comment: Actually I added an alert inside the success function and the alert displays, so getScript is executed, so the point is the script itself is not working. Anyway I'll post another question for an answer. Thanks.